# Align images on one line css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to design a site and I'm trying to align images horizontally and hiding the overflow.

Here's the div

```
<div class="timeline-gallery col-md-12" style="display: inline-block;"> 
    <img src="/media/cache/de/0f/de0fca4d8b894f36a82a343cd150fcb9.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="/media/cache/93/46/9346e937935238a5781beba426a279a1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="/media/cache/a2/53/a2531798d757427e8d5c625d1dfc34bc.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

and the css for the images

```
.timeline-gallery img {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

They occupy the space I'd like but instead are arranged like below
[image]

Comment: can you explain clearly, what you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what do You want ...

```
<div class="timeline-gallery col-md-12"> 
  <div class='col-md-4'>
    <img src="/media/cache/de/0f/de0fca4d8b894f36a82a343cd150fcb9.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-4'>
    <img src="/media/cache/93/46/9346e937935238a5781beba426a279a1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
 <div class='col-md-4'>
    <img src="/media/cache/a2/53/a2531798d757427e8d5c625d1dfc34bc.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
  </div>
</div>
```

Remove `style='display:inline-block;'` from bootstrap column col-md-12. Then add col-md-4 as image container, and CSS for image:

```
  .timeline-gallery img {

    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;

 }
```

But I'm not sure what do You want...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/forj72t6/1/

```css
.timeline-gallery img {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="coantiner-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="timeline-gallery col-md-12"> 
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcST7YDjHjnP5DURcPrZpcFPO6BI6I4kOiqTvNeCy4NRYFbA--5J" class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcST7YDjHjnP5DURcPrZpcFPO6BI6I4kOiqTvNeCy4NRYFbA--5J" class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcST7YDjHjnP5DURcPrZpcFPO6BI6I4kOiqTvNeCy4NRYFbA--5J" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry I wanted the images to be arranged horizontally

Comment: Can the three images be on the same line and have the third hidden by overflow? That's what I wanted so I can make a scrolled by editing margin-left